# Car Collision Problems With Ground

Tags: game-engine, physics

**TL/DR: Collisions at edge of convex hull give physics errors**

I have a very simple rigid body car in Game Engine, and when going over triangle mesh it seems to bounce where Blender decides to cut the triangles.

Okay, simple fix, I made the ground convex hull instead. Now the car seems to bounce at the edge of where I broke up the floor (not off the edge, but to a new section of ground). But it's not all the time either, it's more 1/10 of the time you drive over that line.

I've tried lots of different ways to try and fix it. And though I'm not using Python, it seems more and more that I will have to use it. I'm not looking for realistic car physics like [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/game_engine/physics/types/vehicle.html). But just for something that works.

---

[image]